# Power BI scatter plot

Tags: powerbi, scatter-plot, bubble-chart

I would like to create a scatterplot or bubble graph that will show one point for an employee's annual salary based on total years worked for the company and compare it to all of the other employees.

However, the employee logging in will only be able to see detailed information about their point. All other points need to be anomymized.

I have a control table of employees that is using RLS with a user role.
when the user logs in, They can only see their salary data from other tables joined to the employee control table.

I would like to add a table with all other employee's salary info without their Employee IDs, Names, ETC to display all in a scatter plot.

Thanks.

Comment: include code or your attempts you have tried

Comment: I have not attempted this yet. I require information on the best approach to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what is shown in [this post](http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/archive/2014/04/22/implementing-column-security-with-ssas-tabular-and-dax.aspx) by Darren Gosbell<sup>1</sup>, here is a suggestion for you. My model involves three tables, one with the interesting information and two which are the employee dimension, vertically partitioned into public and private columns.

```
Salary & Experience = 
DATATABLE(
    "Employee ID", INTEGER, "Salary", CURRENCY, "Experience", INTEGER,
    {
        {1, 100000, 20},
        {2, 80000, 5},
        {3, 75000, 0},
        {4, 120000, 6},
        {5, 45000, 35}
    }
)
Employees (Public) =
DATATABLE(
    "Employee ID", INTEGER, "Sex", STRING,
    {
        {1, "F"},
        {2, "M"},
        {3, "F"},
        {4, "M"},
        {5, "F"}
    }
)
Employees (Private) = 
DATATABLE(
    "Employee ID", INTEGER, "Name", STRING,
    {
        {1, "Me"},
        {2, "Fred"},
        {3, "Sally"},
        {4, "Bob"},
        {5, "Irene"}
    }
)
```

We just then set up one-to-many relationships between 'Employees (Public)' -> 'Salary & Experience' and 'Employees (Public)' -> 'Employees (Private)' using the [Employee ID] column.
[image: data model with vertically partitioned dimension table]

We can create some roles which filter the 'Employees (Private)' table based on the identity of the current user.
[image: roles window limiting a role's access to rows in the private partition of the table]

Then we make the scatter plot as you described, being careful to use a unique attribute from the public partition of the employees table as the details for the plot. Note that when viewing as employee "Me" I can see name of that employee, but not another employee.
[image: see own name in scatter]
[image: can't see someone else's name]

I'm sure that your filter you define in the roles will me more interesting than mine.

---

1: Which describes a theoretical implementation of column-level security in SSAS tabular using vertical partitioning.

Comment: This is exactly what I want; THX so much for taking the time to show me step by step.

Comment: Is there a way to highlight the "Me" point in a color and have all other points in one color so that the user knows his point without  hovering?

Comment: None that I can think of at the moment.

Comment: Ok, I have replicated your model and implementation. I was able to identify "ME" by putting the name in the saturation parameter.

Comment: I am now having difficulty adding another requirement:   Each Employee belongs to a separate department and I only want to see the points for my department. In this example, how could I do this with the sex value? if I am a male, then show only male points

Comment: Recommend the second part of this two-part series by Reza Rad http://radacad.com/dynamic-row-level-security-with-power-bi-made-simple | http://radacad.com/dynamic-row-level-security-with-profiles-and-users-in-power-bi